# When is it appropriate to organize code using a class with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abstract-class, organization

While I have a good amount of experience using Python, I found that sometimes it's quite difficult to determine if relevant functions and attributes should be put inside a class. More specifically, I have a function that uses the attributes of the class, and the following functions sequentially use the returned value of the previous function. For example Function 1 --> Function 2 --> Function 3 and so forth with each function returning something.

I wish to understand if it makes sense to use a class in situations like this as it is a common occurrence with me. I want to make sure that the object (sales table) is created in a way that's logical and clean.

So far I've created just a simple class with some attributes and instance methods. I'm not sure how else I can go about it. I have looked up numerous posts on Stacks, articles and many other resources. I believe I have a decent understanding the purpose of a class but less so on when it's appropriate to use it.

To be clear, I'm not asking for help on the functions themselves or their logic (although I appreciate any suggestions!). I just want to know if using a class is the way to go. I did not include any code within the functions as I don't think their logic is relevant to my question (I can add if necessary!)

```
class SalesTable:

    def __init__(self, banner, start_year, start_month, end_year, end_month):
        """These attributes act as filters when searching for the relevant data."""
        self.banner = banner
        self.start_year = start_year
        self.start_month = start_month
        if not end_year:
            self.end_year = start_year
        else:
            self.end_year = end_year
        if not end_month:
            self.end_month = start_month
        else:
            self.end_month = end_month

    def sales_periods(self):
        """Will create a dict with a key as the year and each year will have a list of months as the value. The
        stated attributes are used ONLY here as filters to determine what years and months are included"""
        pass

    def find_sales_period_csv(self):
        """Using the dictionary returned from the function above, will search through the relevant directories and 
        subdirectories to find all the paths for individual csvs where the sales data is stored as determined by the
        value in the dictionary and store the paths in a list"""
        pass

    def csv_to_df(self):
        """Using the list returned from the function above, will take each csv path in the list and convert them into a
        dataframe and store those dateframes in another list"""
        pass

    def combine_dfs(self):
        """Using the list return from the function above, will concatenate all dfs into a single dataframe"""

    def check_data(self):
        """Maybe do some checking here to ensure all relevant data concatenated properly (i.e total row count etc.)"""
```

Ideally I like to return a sales table through the last function (combine_dfs) following the sequence of functions. I can accomplish this task quite easily however, I'm not sure this is the best way I should structure my script or if it logically makes sense, despite it working as I want.

Comment: Move any method that doesn't use `self` out of the class. Basically, you are asking about composition, `f(g(h(x)))`, which doesn't depend on any of `f`, `g`, or `h` being methods or regular functions. Does anything other than `sales_periods` use the `SalesTable` attributes?

Comment: And, if after ejecting all the "regular" functions from your class, if you are left with nothing but `__init__` and one other method, chances are good that the other method should *also* just be a function that takes the additional parameters from the now-defunct `__init__` method, and the class should be scrapped.

Comment: Yes, only the sales_periods function takes in the attributes. So would it be correct to say that it only makes sense to use a class when more than one method uses the instance attributes specified. Thank you for your explanation it was really clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since only `sales_periods` actually uses the instance attributes, and it returns a `dict`, not another instance of `SalesTable`, all the other methods can be moved out of the class and defined as regular functions:

```
class SalesTable:

    def __init__(self, banner, start_year, start_month, end_year, end_month):
        ...

    def sales_periods(self):
        # ...
        return some_dict


def find_sales_period_csv(dct):
    return some_list

def csv_to_df(lst):
    return some_list

def combine_dfs(lst):
    return some_df

def check_data(df):
    pass
```

And you'll call them all in a chained fashion:

```
x = SalesTable(...)
check_data(combine_dfs(csv_to_df(find_sales_period_csv(x.sales_periods()))))
```

Now take a closer look at your class: you only have two methods, `__init__` and `sales_periods`. Unless `__init__` does something expensive that you don't want to repeat (and you would call `sales_periods` on the same instance multiple times), the entire class can be reduced to a single function that combines `__init__` and the `sales_period` method:

```
def sales_periods(banner, start_year, start_month, end_year, end_month):
    ...
    return some_dict

check_data(combine_dfs(csv_to_df(find_sales_period_csv(sales_periods(...)))))
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Would it be inappropriate to use static methods as an alternative, since they don't use any attributes?

Comment: You could, but these functions don't sound like they have anything to do with `SalesTable` otherwise. Static methods are usually less general purpose, being clearly defined only as helpers for "regular" methods or at least somewhat related to the class, if not any particular instance of the class.

Comment: Gotcha, so if say I had another function that did something to or for sales_periods (Like maybe some sort of formatting et.c) and it didn't use the instance attributes, it would be more appropriate to have it as a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally there are two main uses for a `class`:

1) To prevent repetition. If you create the same object multiple times than it should be in a class.

2) To group things together.  It is a lot easier to read someones code if all the related functions and attributes are grouped together. This also makes *maintainability* and *portability* easier.

It is common for methods to call each other within a class since methods should ideally not be longer than 30 lines (though different groups have different standards). If you are calling methods only from within a class than that method should be `private` and you should append `__` (two underscores) before that method.

Comment: So the sales table object will only be created once, so based on number 1, I would imagine a class would be inappropriate. However, my functions and attributed are related in that you need the attributes for the first function and first function for the second and so forth so I think number 2 is applicable. Is it just a matter of judgement? I'll also keep the underscores in mind! Thanks!

Comment: @OskiTuranoglu Typically, yes it is a matter of judgement.  If one of the two uses applies you should probably use a class. You will find that by [encapsulating](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/) your code you will have an easier time fixing bugs and making changes since all the logic is done by [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#An_information-hiding_mechanism).

Comment: In my personal experience I always try to put my code in classes. There are very few instances when I do not use a class.

Comment: The only exception is if I am doing a quick/short script to do something simple like rename all files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

If a bunch of data and functions seem to live together, which is to say you typically refer to them both at the same time, then you have good reason to think you may have an object on your hands.

Another good reason is if there's a natural name for the object. Weird, I know, but it really is a useful guiding principle.

Reading up on [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) may also give you some food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It is a "table" so I thought it seemed natural, although it seems more abstract than real. I will take a read, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

People new to OOP tend to create too many classes (I know I did in the beginning). One problem with that is code readability: when code uses a custom class, it's often necessary to read the class definition to figure out what the class is supposed to do. If the code uses built-in types only, it's usually easier to figure out. Also, the complex internal state that is a natural feature of classes often is a source of subtle bugs and makes code more difficult to reason about.

Comment: I see. So I actually have to create 4 tables, all different in terms of the data but will eventually all have to be data frames individually (same output as above). I thought making a separate module for each table and each module would have a class to create an instance of one would make making changes and portability easier. Would you say than simply making 4 different modules with no classes be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

[This book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-3-object-oriented-programming-second-edition)  is quite helpful

Each of your methods above look like they relate to the class. So lets say you had defined a bunch of functions outside the class, and you were passing the same set of ten variables as arguments to each of them. That would be a sign that they should be in the class. Accessing and modifying too many variables and passing them to other functions as arguments instead of having them as class attributes which get modified inside each of the methods would be a sign that you had failed to take advantage of one of the benefits of classes. In that book, I remember a section where they went into detail about various signs that your code needs OOP.